# MS Office DVD failing to mount

Tags: windows-10, installation, microsoft-office, dvd, automount

I'm at a small charity installing MS Office on several Windows 10 laptops (they already have Office installed on most of their PCs and apparently have a site license, although nobody knows who installed it originally... some contractor?)

I've been handed a DVD which apparently contains office. It has a .iso file called 'SW_DVD5_Office_2013_W32_English_MLF_X18-53902'. When I click on it (Attempt to mount it) Windows tells me "virtual hard disk files cannot be mounted from image files or from removable media that isn't formatted with NTFS file system"

What's going on? How can I mount the installer and install office?

Comment: The error message is pretty self-explanatory though? Copy the file to your PC and it should work. Alternatively, demand that this amateurish attempt at burning an image to a DVD be corrected.

Comment: can you go on this site: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/download-and-install-or-reinstall-office-2013-on-a-pc-7c695b06-6d1a-4917-809c-98ce43f86479 but since its about a site licence maybe you need to log in to the volume licence and check it there or call your microsoft rep about this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to mount it with a third party tool like [WinCDEMu](http://wincdemu.sysprogs.org/) or [RedFox Virtual Clone Drive](https://www.redfox.bz/en/virtual-clonedrive.html), which I highly suggest?

It seems that the ISO file you have is not supported by the Microsoft ISO mount process.

Answer (score 0):

As sonomar mentioned, Windows doesn't know what to do with it for some reason.  Try one of the programs he mentioned, or alternatively download 7zip and try extracting the iso like you would a zip file.

https://www.7-zip.org/download.html